# Access helper script already attached to current gameObject

Tags: unity, c#

I currently have an object in my scene that needs to do many things (move, sleep, reproduce, etc..). I thought it would be good practice to refactor my code and extract each type of action my agent can do into its own scripts which I could then call in a main script. I have done this for movement code and it works when there is just one Agent in the scene however, when creating multiple agent objects in my scene and pressing play I've been getting undesired behavior, only one agent moves while all the other idle. I was wondering if there was a way to access an instance of a script already attached to a gameObject, instead of using Component.FindObjectOfType<>();

Here's the movement script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

//This class contains methods for moving an agent throughout the space, and searching for food when hungry.
//Every method in this class is made public as it will be used in the Agent.cs file.
public class MoveAgent : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public gridScript gs;
    public Vector2 pos;
    public float searchRadius;
    public DayNightCycle dy;
    private GameObject foodTarget = null;
    private bool inRotation = false; 
    public float rotateSpeed = 5f;
    private Quaternion direction;

   List<GameObject> nearbyFood = new List<GameObject>();
   Vector2 prevPos;

    public void getStartPos(){
        pos = new Vector2(Random.Range(0,gs.grid.GetLength(1)),Random.Range(0,gs.grid.GetLength(0)));
         this.transform.position = gs.getGridPosition(pos);
        gs.occupySpace(pos);
        rotateSpeed *= Random.Range(0.5f,1f);
        getNewPos();
    }

    public void getNewPos(){
        float f = Random.Range(0.0f,1.0f);
        int newX = 0,newY = 0;
        if(f < 0.25){
            newX =  1;
            direction = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-90,Vector3.up);
            }else if(f <= 0.5 && f >= 0.25){
            newX = -1;
            direction = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90,Vector3.up);
        } else if(f <= 0.75 && f >= 0.5){
            newY =  1;
            direction = Quaternion.AngleAxis(180,Vector3.up);
        }else if(f <= 1 && f >= 0.75){
            newY = - 1;
            direction = Quaternion.AngleAxis(0,Vector3.up);
        }
        prevPos = pos;
        pos.x += (float)newX;
        pos.y += (float)newY;
    }

    public bool rotating(){
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (transform.rotation, direction, Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);
        //Currently getting odd behaviour due to floating point values, so just set the new rotation direction explicitly if the distance between them is minimal
        if(Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation,direction) < 0.00000001)this.transform.rotation = direction;
        if(transform.rotation.eulerAngles == direction.eulerAngles){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void moveToNextPos(){
        gs.leaveSpace(prevPos);
      if(!gs.isOccupied(pos)){
            gs.occupySpace(pos);
            this.transform.position = gs.getGridPosition(pos);
      }
    }


    //if theres food nearby then search for it
    public void searchForFood(){
        int x=0,y=0;
        //constantly selecting a new foodTarget leads to undesired behaviours,
        //so only find a target if the current foodTarget gameObject is null
        if(foodTarget == null ){ 
            GameObject[] food = nearbyFood.ToArray();
            GameObject foodToFind = new GameObject();
            foodToFind.transform.position = new Vector3(-999,-999,-999);
            if(food.Length > 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < food.Length; i++){
                    if(Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position,food[i].transform.position) < Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position,foodToFind.transform.position)){
                        foodToFind = food[i];
                    }
                    foodTarget = foodToFind;
                }
            }
            Destroy(foodToFind);
        }

        if(this.transform.position.x > foodTarget.transform.position.x){
            x = -1;
            direction = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90,Vector3.up);

        }else if(this.transform.position.x < foodTarget.transform.position.x){
            x = 1;
            direction = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-90,Vector3.up);
        }else if(this.transform.position.z > foodTarget.transform.position.z && this.transform.position.x == foodTarget.transform.position.x){
            y = -1;
            direction = Quaternion.AngleAxis(0,Vector3.up);
        }else if(this.transform.position.z < foodTarget.transform.position.z && this.transform.position.x == foodTarget.transform.position.x){
            y = 1;
            direction = Quaternion.AngleAxis(180,Vector3.up);
        }

        //leaving this here because its useful for debugging
        //foodTarget.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white; 
        prevPos = pos;
        pos.x += (float)x;
        pos.y += (float)y;
    }

    //Check the map for all food sources, create a list of all food nearby to an agent
    //if the list is empty then theres no food nearby, so just random walk
    public bool checkArea(){ 
        nearbyFood = new List<GameObject>();
        GameObject[] food =  GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Food");
        for(int i = 0; i < food.Length; i++){
            if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, food[i].transform.position) < this.searchRadius){
                nearbyFood.Add(food[i].gameObject);
            }
        }
        return nearbyFood.Count != 0;
    }

    bool V3Equal(Vector3 a, Vector3 b){
        return Vector3.SqrMagnitude(a - b) < 9.99999944E-11f;
    }
    void OnDrawGizmos(){
        if(Application.isPlaying){
            Gizmos.color = Color.white;
            Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(this.transform.position, searchRadius);
            GameObject[] food = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Food");
            Gizmos.DrawLine(this.transform.position,foodTarget.transform.position);
            // for(int i = 0; i < food.Length; i++){
            //     if(Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position,food[i].transform.position) < this.searchRadius)Gizmos.DrawLine(this.transform.position,food[i].transform.position);
            // }
        }
    }

}
```

And here's my scripts that accesses those methods:

```
public class Agent : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField, Range(350,500)]  int energy;
    [SerializeField]private int timeTillNextMove;
    private int counter;
    MoveAgent moveAgent;
    private bool isMoving;

    void Awake(){
        moveAgent = Component.FindObjectOfType<MoveAgent>();
        timeTillNextMove = (int)Random.Range(0,100);
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Random.ColorHSV(0f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f, 1f);
        isMoving = true;
    }
    void Start(){
        timeTillNextMove += (int)Random.Range(0,35);
        counter = timeTillNextMove;
        moveAgent.getStartPos();
    }

    void Update(){
        counter--;
        if(counter <= 0){
           move();
        }
        if(energy == 0){
                Component.FindObjectOfType<gridScript>().leaveSpace(moveAgent.pos);
                DestroyAgentInstance();    
        }
    }
        void move(){
         if(energy < 500 && moveAgent.checkArea()){
                if(moveAgent.rotating() == true){
                    moveAgent.moveToNextPos();
                    counter = timeTillNextMove;
                    energy -= 5;
                    isMoving = false;
                    if(energy < 500 && moveAgent.checkArea() == true)  moveAgent.searchForFood(); else moveAgent.getNewPos();
                }
            }else{
                 if(moveAgent.rotating() == true){
                    moveAgent.moveToNextPos();
                    counter = timeTillNextMove;
                    energy -= 5;
                    isMoving = false;
                    moveAgent.getNewPos();    
                 }
            }
        }

    public void DestroyAgentInstance(){
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider target){
            if(target.gameObject.tag.Equals("Food") == true ){
                    Destroy(target.gameObject);
                    this.energy+=50;
                }
            }
    }
```

Is there a way to somehow only search the gameobject `Agent.cs` is attached to for `moveAgent.cs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot! You can just use `this.getComponent<Name_of_Script>();`

Answer (score 1):

Component.FindObjectOfType<> is a heavy function and you should avoid using it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30310847/gameobject-findobjectoftype-vs-getcomponent).
FindObjectOfType<> returns the first loaded component it can get of specified type. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html

what you want to use is from the level of agent component invoke `gameObject.getComponent<>`https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html